# Confused with this confidence interval statistics

Tags: self-study, confidence-interval

The formula used to compute a confidence interval for the mean of a normal population when n is small is the following.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/vluLbC3.gif]

What is the appropriate t critical value for each of the following confidence levels and sample sizes? (Round the answers to two decimal places.)

(a) 90% confidence, n = 17

(b) 90% confidence, n = 13

(c) 99% confidence, n = 24

(d) 90% confidence, n = 25

(e) 95% confidence, n = 13

thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Where exactly do you need help with these questions?  Please see our [help] for guidance on how to ask good, answerable questions.

Comment: Please read the [tag wiki info](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) for the `self study` tag. It asks rather more of you than just posting the question and hoping for answers.

Answer (score 1):

Critical t-values are calculated as the alpha/2 quantile of the t-distribution with n-1 degrees of freedom, where alpha denotes the significance level (i.e. 1 minus the significance level gives you the % confidence interval). The t-distribution loses one degree of freedom as you estimate the mean from your sample (one restriction).